# Подключение Vue Js пакетов к проекту

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, npm, установка

Здраствуйте, не получается подключить пакеты к проекту, в моем случае палитру к backend админки. В админке использую Yii и Php
Пробовал по инструкции - качаю пакеты через npm, запускаю init, пытался подключить через import и require — не получается. Возможно я что то упускаю? Можете пожалуйста разжевать как правильно подключать пакеты? Если с примером, то было бы вообще великолепно

Answer (score 1):

Придется подключать и импортировать функции, классы Vue в **стандарте ES6**

Но в ряде случаев возможно обойтись подключением Vue из какого-нибудь CDN вроде того

```
<script src=npm.org....vue.js>
```